# Select string value from database with sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

I have a problem. I am trying to get a value (string) from my database. Here is the code I am calling to get the value:

```
public string SelectValueFromTableSettings(string name)
{
    string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Settings.db")))
        {
            return connection.Query<SettingDb>("SELECT Value FROM SettingDb WHERE Name=?", name).ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the code to assign the value to a variable:

```
string SwitchValue = MainActivity.db.SelectValueFromTableSettings(mItems[position].Name);
```

I am supposed to get a value like Nick or Steve, but I get this as value:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CryptoCurrencies.SettingDb]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of enumerating the results of `connection.Query<SettingDb>("...")`, you're calling `ToString()` on it. `connection.Query<SettingDb>()` returns `List<SettingDb>`. Because there's no sensible stringification of `List<T>`, it just has the default `ToString()` which returns `GetType().FullName` or whatever. Instead, loop through the list.

Comment: What am I supposed to do then?

Comment: Loop through the list the query returns. See if there's anything in it.

Comment: when you call `ToString()` on Query result, you are getting the name of the result class which is a list of setting.
Use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `ToString()` to the first data in list and use SettingDb properties to get the desired result.

Comment: should you please post the **SettingsDb** class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a list of objects.

```
connection.Query<SettingDb>("SELECT Value FROM SettingDb WHERE Name=?", name).FirstOrDefault().YourProperty.ToString();
```

Or, simply return the object:

```
public SettingDB SelectValueFromTableSettings(string name)
{
    string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Settings.db")))
        {
            return connection.Query<SettingDb>("SELECT Value FROM SettingDb WHERE Name=?", name).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then acess to the desired property.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot